# IOS/Objective-C: Button Image Not Appearing with Autolayout

Tags: ios, uibutton, autolayout

I have some buttons in a View Controller that uses autolayout.  The buttons all have an image assigned to the image, not background image field.  Frequently, one of the button images disappears.  When I examine it in the visual debugger, it suggests the label is blocking the image.

The issue does not not happen every time.  It happens when you reload the page occasionally.

Here is a picture from visual debugger.  The button whose image is not showing is the highlighted one in the middle.  It is still active in the sense you can click on it.  The image just doesn't appear.

[image]

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on how to fix this.

Comment: Each purple `!` indicates a constraint conflict, which would seem likely related to why the image is not visible. Are you explicitly changing constraints on the buttons' internal elements?

Comment: I am not changing them.  They should always be the same.  The left button is supposed to left (leading) aligned with the line above it.  The middle one should be centered on the line.  And the right one should be right aligned (trailing).  Each button also has a height and width constraint of 30.  Of note, if I display and cancel the VC many times, sometimes the middle one disappears.  Other times the right one disappears.  The left one never disappears.  The middle and right never both disappear at the same time.  Some times all three appear.  Vertically they are baseline aligned.

Comment: Hmmm.. examine your elements a little deeper. What are the constraint conflicts that are being shown?

Comment: I was able to fix it by playing around with the constraints.  I switched some of the the vertical baseline constraints to constraints to elements above and below and for some reason that did trick.  Thx.